# What do "At the top" and "With the letter U" mean in this reddit poll?

Tags: meaning, slang, internet

The [Poll](https://www.reddit.com/r/polls/comments/107mm3p/in_a_list_of_countries_where_do_you_think_the/) asks:

> In a list of countries, where do you think the United States should go?

With only two options:

1. At the top
2. With the letter "U"

What do the two options mean?

There are 300 comments and 7k votes for this poll, so I guess it's not just some typo.

Thanks for any kind of tips.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a list of countries that are otherwise sorted alphabetically.  Should United States be sorted the same as other countries, or should it go at the top of the list.  This question would be asking about a user interface in which people have to select their country, and most respondents would be expected to be American.

So should your pull down list be sorted so that "United States" can be easily found at the top of the list:

```
United States  
Afghanistan  
Albania   
...  
Zambia  
Zimbabwe
```

Or should United States be sorted with the other countries starting "U"

```
Afghanistan  
Albania  
...  
United Kingdom  
United States  
Uraguay  
...  
Zimbabwe
```

Comment: I see. Thanks very much for your explanation!